# (Almost) arbitrary base ints with decorated methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, inheritance, number-systems

After reading [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/198384/return-the-following-string) about returning the "next" string in some alphabet (the digits, followed by upper and lowercase ASCII letters) using Java, I thought, well that's just counting, so why not derive from `int` and make a nice representation, which is very easy in Python.

I borrowed the base conversion code from [`numpy.base_repr`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.2/numpy/core/numeric.py#L2067-L2120) (extending it from max base 36 to 62), but this was not enough. When doing math with these integers, it would be nice if they remained in their base, so I added a class decorator that automatically wraps calls to special methods (in this case the math methods) with the class itself again (taking the base from the first number, in case both have a base). This decorator is adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7589433/4042267).

```
from functools import wraps
from string import digits, ascii_letters


def wrap_math_methods(cls):
    """Wraps a classes math modules with converter,
    so that the result is an instance of the class again."""
    methods = {"__abs__", "__add__", "__and__", "__ceil__", "__div__",
               "__floor__", "__floordiv__", "__invert__", "__lshift__",
               "__mod__", "__mul__", "__neg__", "__or__", "__pos__", "__pow__",
               "__radd__", "__rand__", "__rfloordiv__", "__rlshift__",
               "__rmod__", "__rmul__", "__ror__", "__rpow__", "__rrshift__",
               "__rshift__",  "__rsub__", "__rtruediv__",  "__rxor__",
               "__sub__", "__truediv__", "__xor__"}
    def method_wrapper(method):
        @wraps(method)
        def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # Return a new instance of cls, copying the base
            return cls(method(self, *args, **kwargs), self.base)
        return inner

    for attr_name in dir(cls):
        if attr_name in methods:
            setattr(cls, attr_name, method_wrapper(getattr(cls, attr_name)))
    return cls


@wrap_math_methods
class BaseInt(int):
    """An integer class in arbitrary (up to 62) base.

    Automatically converts results of math operations."""
    digits = digits + ascii_letters

    def __new__(cls, value, base=10):
        if base > len(cls.digits):
            raise ValueError(f"Bases greater than {len(cls.digits)} not handled.")
        elif base < 2:
            raise ValueError("Bases less than 2 not handled.")
        n = super().__new__(cls, value)
        n.base = base
        return n

    def __str__(self):
        """Representation of the number in its base."""
        num = abs(self)
        res = []
        while num:
            res.append(self.digits[num % self.base])
            num //= self.base
        if self < 0:
            res.append('-')
        return ''.join(reversed(res or '0'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = BaseInt(100, 62)
    print(n, repr(n))
    print(n + 1, repr(n + 1))
    print(int(n))

    import math
    assert isinstance(abs(n), BaseInt), "__abs__"
    assert isinstance(n + 1, BaseInt), "__add__"
    assert isinstance(BaseInt(0) and 2, BaseInt), "__and__"  # short circuit
    assert isinstance(math.ceil(n), BaseInt), "__ceil__"
    assert isinstance(n / 2, BaseInt), "__div__"
    assert isinstance(math.floor(n), BaseInt), "__floor__"
    assert isinstance(n // 2, BaseInt), "__floordiv__"
    assert isinstance(~n, BaseInt), "__invert__"
    assert isinstance(n << 2, BaseInt), "__lshift__"
    assert isinstance(n % 2, BaseInt), "__mod__"
    assert isinstance(n * 2, BaseInt), "__mul__"
    assert isinstance(-n, BaseInt), "__neq__"
    assert isinstance(n or 2, BaseInt), "__or__"
    assert isinstance(+n, BaseInt), "__pos__"
    assert isinstance(n ** 2, BaseInt), "__pow__"
    assert isinstance(2 + n, BaseInt), "__radd__"
    assert isinstance(2 and n, BaseInt), "__rand__"
    assert isinstance(2 // n, BaseInt), "__rfloordiv__"
    assert isinstance(2 << n, BaseInt), "__rlshift__"
    assert isinstance(2 % n, BaseInt), "__rmod__"
    assert isinstance(2 * n, BaseInt), "__rmul__"
    assert isinstance(0 or n, BaseInt), "__ror__"  # short circuit
    assert isinstance(2 ** n, BaseInt), "__rpow__"
    assert isinstance(2 >> n, BaseInt), "__rrshift__"
    assert isinstance(n >> 2, BaseInt), "__rshift__"
    assert isinstance(2 - n, BaseInt), "__rsub__"
    # assert isinstance(2 / n, BaseInt), "__rtruediv__"
    assert isinstance(2 ^ n, BaseInt), "__rxor__"
    assert isinstance(n - 2, BaseInt), "__sub__"
    # assert isinstance(n / 2, BaseInt), "__truediv__"
    assert isinstance(n ^ 2, BaseInt), "__xor__"
```

I purposefully wrapped only `__str__` and not `__repr__`, so that one can still see the underlying integer without calls to `int`. Note that `int(str(BaseInt(100, 62)), 62)` fails, because `int` only supports up to base 36. `int(BaseInt(100, 62))` however does not fail, since `BaseInt` inherits from `int`.

I am interested in general comments as well as comments on how to make defining and testing the math methods easier. Comments on the class decorator are also very welcome (would it have been clearer if I had used a metaclass, for example?).

(This class as is does not quite solve the Java question, mostly because of a different order of the digits, but that is fine with me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What strikes me the most with this implementation is that you should already have the decimal representation of the number you want. The base is then just artificial and its only purpose is to have a nice `str` of it.

Instead, you could mimic the `int` constructor:

> ```
> |  Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
> |  are given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point
> |  numbers, this truncates towards zero.
> |  
> |  If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
> |  bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the
> |  given base.  The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded
> |  by whitespace.  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.
> |  Base 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.
> |  >>> int('0b100', base=0)
> |  4
> ```

So, basically, your `__new__` would look like the following:

```python
def __new__(cls, value, base=None):
    if not isinstance(value, numbers.Number) and base is None:
        base = 10
    if base is not None:
        if base > len(cls.digits):
            raise ValueError(f"Bases greater than {len(cls.digits)} not handled.")
        elif base < 2:
            raise ValueError("Bases less than 2 not handled.")
        if not isinstance(value, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
            raise TypeError("can't convert non-string with explicit base")
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            value = bytes(value).decode()
        value = sum(self.digits.index(letter) * base ** i for i, letter in enumerate(reversed(value)))
    else:
        base = 10
    self = super().__new__(cls, value)
    self.base = base
    return self
```

This won't let you write `BaseInt(100, 62)` anymore. Instead you either use `BaseInt('1C', 62)` or `i = BaseInt(100); i.base = 62`. Or you could have a classmethod `BaseInt.from_int(value, base=10)` wrapping it for you.

But it feels neater since `BaseInt(str(BaseInt(v, x)), x)` would work as expected, which is IMHO nicer.

Answer (score 3):

A little nitpicking: I'd change

```
for attr_name in dir(cls):
    if attr_name in methods:
        setattr(cls, attr_name, method_wrapper(getattr(cls, attr_name)))
return cls
```

into

```
for attr_name in methods:
    if hasattr(cls, attr_name):
        setattr(cls, attr_name, method_wrapper(getattr(cls, attr_name)))
return cls
```

The reason being, that your set of methods you're interested in overwriting is a constant. If you have a derived class with lots of properties, you'll avoid unnecessary iterations.

Comment: Thus I’d also recommend to change from using a `set` to using a `list` or a `tuple`.

Comment: Yeah. A tuple would definitely be more fitting here. Or maybe a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset).

Comment: A tuple would do fine. The methods to overwrite will not change (at runtime) and I only needed the `set` for fast `in` lookup.